# how can I convert mysql result into JSON object using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to convert a mysql resource id to JSON object to be sent as a response for ajax call
this is the code that I´ve tried to use

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM `inquiry` WHERE 1";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if($res)
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

and I get this error message

```
Warning: [json] (php_json_encode) type is unsupported, encoded as null in /home/smartco/public_html/kb/q.php on line 6
```

null

how can I do it

Answer (score 2):

Change your code something to

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 $output[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

You're encoding the resource id.